# TypeError: this.$el.bracket is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins

I've been trying every answer I can find for hours now... Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to use [jQuery Tournament Bracket](http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/) in my react component. I've tried importing jquery like `import $ from "jquery";` which works as expected, but when I do `import "jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js"` or even `import "jquery-bracket"` I see the following error on my browser.

`TypeError: this.$el.bracket is not a function`

I followed [this tutorial](https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-using-jquery-with-react.html) on how to implement a jQuery plugin in React. Below is the code for the component I'm referring too.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import $ from "jquery";

// Tried //
// import jQueryBracket from "jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js";
// import "jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js";
// Currently using //
import "jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js";


class Bracket extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            teams: "",
            scores: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let minimalData = {
            teams: [
                ["Team 1", "Team 2"],
                ["Team 3", null],
                ["Team 4", null],
                ["Team 5", null]
            ],
            results: [
                [
                    [[1, 0], [null, null], [null, null], [null, null]],
                    [[null, null], [1, 4]],
                    [[null, null], [null, null]]
                ]
            ]
        }

        let resizeParameters = {
            teamWidth: 100,
            scoreWidth: 30,
            matchMargin: 25,
            roundMargin: 45,
            init: minimalData
        };

        this.$el = $(this.el);
        this.$el.bracket(resizeParameters);
        // $("#bracket").bracket(resizeParameters);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div ref={el => this.el = el}>Bracket goes here...</div>
                {/*<div id="bracket"></div>*/}
            </>

        )
    }
}

export default Bracket;
```

Comment: where is the error TypeError: this.$el.bracket is not a function coming from? Is it from react page or the import "jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js" file? From glancing at the tutorial, it looks like you need to add `import $ from "jquery";` to your jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js file also.

Comment: @PowerGlove I've already tried `import $ from "jquery";` in `jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js`. As I said above "I see the following error on my browser". Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing `jquery.bracket.min.js` from `node_modules` as that gave me much trouble, I tried moving `jquery.bracket.min.js` to the components directory. I'm not sure why but after I fixed the import issue then `eslint` threw a ton of errors. To fix the `eslint` errors temporarily I included the following line at the top of `jquery.bracket.min.js`

`/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */`